# Problem with kafka - Failed with result 'exit-code', status=1/FAILURE

Tags: apache-kafka

I tried to install apache-kafka several times but I always had this problem. I'm using ubuntu on my virtual machine. When I'm trying to activate kafka service using `sudo systemctl start kafka`
and then controlling if it's working at first, the output is "active (running)", but if I double-check it and the output is "failed (Result: exit-code) ". And I tried `sudo systemctl enable kafka` but it didn't work.

This is the output:

● kafka.service

```
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-05-26 05:40:22 PDT; 3s ago
 Process: 8098 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c /home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka/co>
 Main PID: 8098 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 May 26 05:40:19 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started kafka.service.
 May 26 05:40:22 ubuntu systemd[1]: kafka.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 May 26 05:40:22 ubuntu systemd[1]: kafka.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

You can see the full output attached

[image]

I also tried `journalctl -xe` and it recommended using `./gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.5`, and I download it, at first it seemed to work, but the following day I had the same problem ( kafka.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.). And if I tried `journalctl -xe` I had an output that you can see attached.

[image]

With zookeeper I had no problem, it's always active.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you also check server.log file generated by kafka? if unclear, please attach those logs here.

Comment: 1) Does Kafka start without systemctl? 2) Show `journalctl -u kafka` 3) unrelated, but your data is writing to /tmp according to the Zookeeper logs, which will be deleted if the machine ever restarts, causing you to lose all Kafka data

Comment: If you want systemctl and apt packages, you could use Confluent Platform - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html#systemd-ubuntu-debian-install

Comment: @RishabhSharma i answered to your questions

Comment: @OneCricketeer i answered to your questions

Answer (score 17):

Open the file `meta.properties`.

In my case, it was located at the path `/home/kafka/logs/meta.properties`

Just comment the the `cluster.id` with a `#`

Restart zookeeper and kafka.

Comment: This worked for me, but I am interested to know why?

Comment: It works for me, too. But I do have the same question with Joe Beams. Can someone explain this, please ? 
Somehow, I think after I comment that cluster.id, kafka starts and finds no cluster and it will recreate a new one , instead of running with the old error cluster id

Comment: worked for me as well, though like others would like to know why and is this something that is going to be reoccurring?

Comment: i do't have `meta.properties` file

Comment: checked by this command `find / -name meta.properties`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue by following the tutorial from well known site. I fixed the problem by doing all from the scratch this way.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

I downloaded latest BINARY release from here https://kafka.apache.org/downloads. I used https://dlcdn.apache.org/kafka/3.0.0/kafka_2.13-3.0.0.tgz

```
sudo wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/kafka/3.0.0/kafka_2.13-3.0.0.tgz
```

Unpack and move

```
tar xzf kafka_2.13-3.0.0.tgz
mv kafka_2.13-3.0.0 /usr/local/kafka
```

edit zookeeper unit file

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.service
```

add this content

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Zookeeper server
Documentation=http://zookeeper.apache.org
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Edit Kafka systemd unit file

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/kafka.service
```

and add the content below. **Note: You must change JAVA_HOME=path to your path**

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Kafka Server
Documentation=http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html
Requires=zookeeper.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="JAVA_HOME=REPLACE-THIS-WITH-YOUR-PATH"
ExecStart=/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka/config/server.properties
ExecStop=/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload the systemd daemon to apply new changes.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Start zookeeper and kafka

```
sudo systemctl start zookeeper
sudo systemctl start kafka
```

check kafka status now, it should be running

```
sudo systemctl status kafka
```

Comment: ty bro! Instructions still working in 2022

Comment: Did you forget "Setting the JAVA_HOME Environment Variable" part in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-20-04 and the memory 1G was not enough

Comment: to find `JAVA_HOME` do: `java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'` it should be like this: java.home = `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: I rebooted the (physical) server (and got OP's error(it worked before)), the JAVA_HOME seems to be the magic trick...

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to build kafka project before running it:

```
./gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.6
```

Note that you need to have Java installed.

Answer (score 0):

> tried to install apache-kafka several times

Kafka doesn't come with Systemd scripts. Follow the ***official*** Apache Kafka website to see how you start it without systemctl

If you want to install on Ubuntu, [Confluent Community edition](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html#systemd-ubuntu-debian-install) allows you to do `apt-get install` to get both Kafka and Zookeeper

---

Your error shows an InconsistentClusterIdException, which means you need to wipe the data directories for Zookeeper and Kafka so that the broker will start in a fresh state

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found out that the system actually has 2 folder kafka so when the service started, it said "exit-code"
-> My solution for my problem is delete 1 folder and keep folder /home/kafka

Answer (score 0):

In my case Kafka didn't start in the first place, I reassigned a different logs folder to server.properties files and provided necessary rights to the folder, and restarted both the zookeeper and Kafka services, and then they seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a Source Download
which I was : `kafka-3.3.1-src.tgz`

**use binary version**
`Scala 2.13  - kafka_2.13-3.3.1.tgz`

You can download it from https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I installed kafka on a test server and got the same error.
I looked in Htop to see what is loading the CPU.
Stopped unnecessary processes

```
servise stop "SERVICENAME".
```

I launched kafka again and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with cluster id, if you open the server log of Kafka which is mostly located at /home/kafka/logs/server.log
You will find some below kind of logs

```
ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: The Cluster ID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX doesn't match stored clusterId Some(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) in meta.properties. The broker is trying to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper. connect may be wrong.
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:218)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

So what you need to do is just delete that meta.properties from the log directory (this log directory will be as per your Kafka server.properties configuration)
Then just  restaet zookerpper and kafka.
That's it, It will work.